# How do I represent the addition of 2 process outputs being fed to a third process in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am creating a flow diagram to detail the steps involved in the business logic of an API. I want to show the outputs from 2 process blocks getting added and then fed as an input to the next process. This is what I have done now:

[image: screenshot of diagram]

Is there any specific component which can be used to represent this?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Rather than a question about a specific problem with using a web app, this looks like a question about the knowledge field / domain. Computer Sciences and, more specifically, Software Engineering might be those fields. I suggest you start looking at [softwareengineering.se].